# Is It possible to have a Grails UI Dialog without buttons

Tags: grails, yui

I am working with a grails app, and would like to use a modal grails UI dialog box to hold my loading image.  I would then control the closing of the box from JavaScript when my event returns (or a timeout happens).  I am already using Grails UI dialog box on the page, so I thought I would do this with another dialog box that holds the loading image.  Is it possible to have a Grails UI dialog box without buttons at the bottom?

Comment: what's Grails UI, are you referring to the Grails JQuery UI plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went the route of using CSS to hide the close container and footer dialog.  Given that my dialog had an id of loading; adding the following CSS keeps the user from having a way to close the dialog:

```
#loading.yui-panel .container-close { 
    background-image: none;
    visibility: hidden;
} 

#loading div.ft {
    display: none;
}
```